# Display original price and final price in catalog products list

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I'm using magento enterprise 1.13.0.1.
When I apply special price for a product, base and final price are visible in both product page and catalog products list.
But when I apply catalog promotion price rule, final and base price are visible in product page, but in catalog products list only base price is visible. how should I fix it?
Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is something to do with your theme as I have tested this with a clean installation and the special price and regular price is shown on search, category and product list.

Answer (score 5):

Poonya,you can load the product by  product id

```
$pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$OrgPrice=$pro->getPrice();
$finalPrice=$pro->getFinalPrice();
```

Hope ,it will help you..
Or Goes to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Product/List.php` copy to  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Product/List.php` then

find function

```
getLoadedProductCollection()

     public function getLoadedProductCollection()
       {
            $Collection=$this->_getProductCollection();
 $Collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice();
return  $Collection; 

        }
```

same change need for  `Mage>CatalogSearch>Block>Result.php`
under: list.phtml in foreach  add

```
$_product->getFinalPrice();
```

Comment: Thank. But I want know why price block in catalog products list doesn't show final price that calculated by catalog rules.

Comment: can you please enabled flat table

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER make a `load()` inside the `foreach()` of the product list, it is a performance killer. Whatever the error is, fix the error, add missing attributes via observer or `config.xml` to the collection but NEVER `load()` ... argh. sorry being mad about this.

Answer (score 1):

try to unset final price ($_product->unsFinalPrice()), so it is calculated.